# Arithmetic progressions that generate an infinite number of powers of 2?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic-functions

For an arithmetic progression of the form $a_i = ki, i \in \mathbb{N}$, the question is trivial - if $k$ is a power of 2, then the progression will generate an infinite number of powers of 2, and no powers of 2 for any other case.

I'm having trouble figuring out the more general $a_0 \neq 0 $ case. What form does the progression $a_0 + k\mathbb{N}$ have to take to generate an infinite number of powers of 2? I.e., if an arithmetic progression generates an infinite number of powers of 2, what will the relationship between $a_0$ and $k$ look like?

Answer (score 0):

Fix a common difference $d$. Take the  $d$ arithmetic progressions $A_0,A_1,\ldots, A_{d-1}$  all with common difference $d$ with the first term for $A_i$ chosen as  $i$. They partition the set of  positive integers. As they are finite in number at least one of them should contain infinitely many powers of 2.

Comment: Wow, that was pretty straightforward. Is there any way to determine which sequences $A_i$ will contain infinitely many powers of 2 for a fixed difference $d$?

Comment: If   $i$ and $d$ have some common factor $k>2$, then every element the corresponding A.P. $A_i$ will be divisible by that $k$, and can never be a power of $2$. So choose $i$ such that $\gcd(i,d)=1$ or $2$. This cuts down the search space.

Comment: One may also allow  the gcd to be a power of 2 instead of just 1  or 2.